# npm start returns error 127 while setting up angular-seed application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ubuntu, npm, bower

I am trying to setup [angular-seed application](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed).

I have installed nodejs with `sudo apt-get install nodejs`

Installed npm with `sudo apt-get install npm`

Installed bower with `sudo apt-get install bower -g`

Installed nodejs-legacy with `sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`

Opened my angular-seed application, ran `npm install`. This ran perfectly without any errors.

To start the server, I'm trying to use `npm start`, but it is returning the following information and error.

```
> angular-seed@0.0.0 prestart /home/venki/Downloads/angular-seed
> npm install


> angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall /home/venki/Downloads/angular-seed
> bower install


> angular-seed@0.0.0 start /home/venki/Downloads/angular-seed
> http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1

sh: 1: http-server: not found
npm ERR! weird error 127
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Please let me know if any further information is necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assumed that http-server will be installed by default by nodejs but it turns out that it doesn't.

I installed http-server using

```
sudo npm install -g http-server
```

Just ran npm start after this. That's it, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 6):

I had to run both the following commands;

```
sudo npm install -g http-server

apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

And then my program trying to use NPM operated correctly.

Answer (score 5):

I installed `nodejs-legacy` using the following:

```
apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

Then just run `npm` after this.